# asp.net web service : sending json within json

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm using jquery to send a json string to an ASMX web service. The code behind for the web service method definition looks like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string DoMyProcess(string TheDataID, string TheUserID, string TheData) {
```

The string TheData is a javascript object MyObject that I serialize using

```
var TheData = JSON.stringify(MyObject);
```

The jquery part that sends the json looks like this:

```
var AjaxData = '{"TheDatatID":"' + DatatID + '","TheUserID":"' + UserID + '","TheData":"' + TheData + '"}';

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../WebServices/MyServices.asmx/DoMyProcess",
      data: AjaxData,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      cache: "false",
      success: RequestSuccess,
      error: RequestError
    });
```

As it is, I get a 500 error and the debugger doesn't even fire in VS. However, if I replace var TheData = JSON.stringify(MyObject); with

```
var TheData = "test";
```

I'm able to get the debugger to break on the first line of the code behind file.

This must be the result of a problem when sending json within json; it should work but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: When you get the web method to raise in the debugger by setting `var TheData = "test"` are the other parameters properly populated (on the server-side), like `TheDataID`?

Comment: Have you tried calling stringify on AjaxData? `data: JSON.stringify(AjaxData),`

Comment: TheData is specified as string not object.  Try to declare TheData as object (MyObject?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you can use [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for more details about Error 500.

But I think the mistake is at sending JSON in JSON. You must replace character \" to \"

example:

`var TheData = JSON.stringify(MyObject).replace(new RegExp('\"', 'g'),'\\"');`